# Restassured: How Can we compare each element in Json array to one particular Same value in Java using Hemcrest Matchers, not using Foreach loop

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Restassured: How Can we compare each element in Json array to one particular Same value in Java using Hemcrest Matchers, not using Foreach loop.

```json
{
  "id": 52352,
  "name": "Great Apartments",
  "floorplans": [
    {
      "id": 5342622,
      "name": "THE STUDIO",
      "fpCustomAmenities": [
        {
          "displaySequence": 2,
          "amenityPartnerId": "gadasd",
          "display": true,
          "leased": true
        },
        {
          "displaySequence": 13,
          "amenityPartnerId": "sdfsfd",
          "display": true,
          "leased": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4321020,
      "name": "THE First Bed",
      "fpCustomAmenities": [
        {
          "displaySequence": 4,
          "amenityPartnerId": "gadasd",
          "display": true,
          "leased": true
        },
        {
          "displaySequence": 15,
          "amenityPartnerId": "hsfdsdf",
          "display": true,
          "leased": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to compare that Leased=true for all the leased nodes at all the levels in the json response...

I have working code...

```java
List<List<Boolean>> displayedvaluesfpStandardAmenities =
        when().get(baseUrl + restUrl).
                then().statusCode(200).log().ifError().
                extract().body().jsonPath().getList("floorplans.fpCustomAmenities.display");

for (List<Boolean> displayedStandardList : displayedvaluesfpStandardAmenities) {
    for (Boolean isDisplayedTrue : displayedStandardList) {
        softAssert.assertTrue(isDisplayedTrue);
    }
}
```

But the issue is I need the code to be in simple format using either Hemcrest Matchers or Restaussred Matchers and  try simplistic way like Below, ( which is not working)

```java
when().get(baseUrl + restUrl).
then().assertThat().body("floorplans.fpCustomAmenities.display",equalTo("true"));
```

The error I am getting is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path floorplans.fpCustomAmenities.display doesn't match.
Expected: true
  Actual: <[[true, true], [true, true]]>
```

So what I need is the that all thes 'display' nodes in the json response where ever it is need to compared with "true", so that my test can Pass.

I have an alternate solution like mentioned above, but All I need is working solution using matchers.

Comment: Can you try to put put the expected result in collection of  List<List<boolean>> which will be your collection  and compare the same , guess that should work .

when().get(baseUrl + restUrl).
then().assertThat().body("floorplans.fpCustomAmenities.display",equalTo(<Collection>));

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fpCustomAmenities` arrays are not empty, you can use the following solution;

```
when().get(baseUrl + restUrl).then()
            .body("floorplans.findAll { it }.fpCustomAmenities" + // 1st line
             ".findAll { it }.leased.each{ a -> println a }" +  // 2nd line
            ".grep{ it.contains(false) }.size()", equalTo(0));  // 3rd line
```

Here from the 1st line, we return each object in `fpCustomAmenities` array.

From the 2nd line we get boolean value of `leased` in each `fpCustomAmenities` object to a boolean array ([true, true]).

Each boolean array is printed from `.each{ a -> println a }`. I added it only to explain the answer. It is not relevant to the solution.

From 3rd line we check whether, if there is a `false` in each boolean array. `grep()` will return only the arrays which has a `false`. And then we get the filtered array count. Then we check whether it is equal to `0`.

Check [groovy documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) for more details.

### Or

This solution does not use any Matchers. But this works.

```
String responseBody = when().get(baseUrl + restUrl).
then().extract().response().getBody().asPrettyString();

Assert.assertFalse(responseBody.contains("\"leased\": false"));
```